# Tier 2 UK Visa for university lecturer position

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas

What NFQ level is a university lecturer position? It is a PhD level post.

Answer (score 4):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Qualifications_Framework#England.2C_Wales_and_Northern_Ireland), a PhD is equivalent to NQF level 8.

The UK's [Codes of Practice for Skilled Workers](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423732/codes_of_practice_april_2015.pdf) talks about "occupations skilled to PhD level" rather than NFQs above 6, but (page 33) includes university lecturer positions in this category.